# XML Text Format

Tags: xml, editor, text-formatting

Does anyone know of a good program where I can paste in xml (getting it from a System.out in my java class) and it will format the xml so it's not a really long line of text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like [XMLPad](http://www.wmhelp.com/). It has a nice formatter plus a bunch of visualisers such as tree view and grid view. There is also a nice interactive XPath query tool and probably many more features.

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio does this (you can download the express verison for free).

If not, Try Liquid XML - it's free, and it's also got an xpath visualiser which is very handy.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try your favorite browser? You can't really paste it, but you can open any XML file and both IE and Firefox will display a nice, collapsible tree view of the XML hierarchy.

Comment: This is what I'm doing now, but just thought there might be a quicker way rather than saving to a file each time - my laziness coming through! :)

Comment: Does your IDE provide such a thing? The Visual Studio debugger has some handy XML visualization built-in, so you can see the formatted XML right in the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

If you have it already, try visual studio (otherwise it is perhaps too much to download =))
Visual Studio formats the xml very nice, you can edit it, and you have a collapsible tree view.
Just paste it in visual studio then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> and you get formatted xml code.

Answer (score 1):

Notepad++ if you don't want to use a XML editor.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like more control over how the formatted text looks, you could try an [XML formatter](http://www.kitebird.com/software/xmlformat/)

Answer (score 0):

You can reformat XML files in Eclipse using Source > Format

Answer (score 0):

you can try something online such as https://onlinetool.app/ext/xml_formatter